# Indonesian culture and Shadowhunters / The Mortal Instruments series?

Tags: dialogue, reference, shadowhunters

I've first remembered Maia giving Simon a free shot on Hunter's Moon, saying 'Gratis' which means 'free' in Indonesian. Magnus Bane is mix white-Indonesian. A Keris, Indonesian artistic weapon, the sword-like weapon Magnus Bane mentioned his mom used to take her own life. And in season 3B of Shadowhunters, an episode 3x19 is titled in Indonesian, 'Aku Cinta Kamu' which means 'I love you' (and later in the teaser Magnus mentioned it's Indonesian although it's valid for Melayu, too).

Is there any backstory regarding the appearance of Indonesian influences in the TV series?

Comment: Gratis is also *Latin* for "free".

Comment: @Paulie_D yes, I am aware of it, too. :D

Comment: It's *also* Spanish for free ;)

Answer (score -1):

The serie is based on the novel of Cassandra Clare (The Mortal Instruments Saga), the author of the book Cassie make the character of Magnus with that personality and with that ethic.

So in answer to your question, is not something from the tv show, is not like "influencing this", is just Magnus is from Indonesia, they have to say it and put things about where he is from.

<3.